# How can I override toString in java using an integer array?

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I need to print the array in this order example: [1, 2, 3, 4], but I don't know how to do it. I started like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        return "[" + a[i] + ", "+ "]";
    }
return null;
```

But I only got the first element printed like [1, ]. Can you help me?

Comment: You shouldn't be returning from inside the loop: you need to build up the toString, and then return it after the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the string in the loop, but don't return until you have processed all the elements:

```
@Override String toString() {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append("[");
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; ++i) {
    sb.append(a[i]);
    sb.append(", ");
  }
  if (a.length > 0) {
    sb.append(a[a.length - 1]);
  }
  sb.append("]");
  return sb.toString();
}
```

I'm assuming that you want to append all elements in the array, you are not intentionally excluding the last one.

Using a `StringBuilder` is preferable to plain string concatenation, since it is more efficient to accumulate lots of strings that way.

Answer (score 3):

Call `Arrays.toString(a)`:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

*Output*

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Better to correct the current OP code before giving him the built in method :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't return with single iteration. You have to build the string for all the iterations and then return from there .

```
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            builder.append(a[i]).append(",");
        }
        builder.append("]");
        if (builder.length() > 1)
        builder.setLength(builder.length() - 1);
        return result;
```

Seems you are learning about arrays and playing with loops.

If you want to use any built in method to do the job use [`Arrays.toString(a);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-)

Comment: That's excessive. Truncate the builder instead: `if (builder.length() != 0) builder.setLength(builder.length() - 1)` before `append("]")`.

Comment: @Andreas Hmm fails in case of empty array. But Idea is good to avoid regex :)

Comment: Fails how? The `if` statement prevents that.

Comment: I said *before* `append("]")`, otherwise you're removing the `]`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are returning at the first loop iteration.

There are other better and cleaner ways to do it like using:

```
Arrays.toString(array)
```

So, you can have:

```
@Override 
String toString() {
    return Arrays.toString(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement also produces the desired output

```
System.out.print(Arrays.asList(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[] a = {1,2,3,4};
    String res=null;
    int num;
    res = "[";


    for (int i = 0;  i < a.length;  i++) {

      num = a[i];
      res = res + num +",";

    }
    res = res + "]";
System.out.println (res);
}
```

We build the string during the loop appending to the previous string the next number until the end. Then we print the full string! :)